# how to start with unit testing of Ext JS app using Jasmine framework

Tags: unit-testing, extjs, jasmine

I want to learn how to start with unit testing of Ext JS app using Jasmine framework. Please tell me with simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Bryntum's [Siesta](https://www.bryntum.com/docs/siesta/) test tool.